# Is there a way to get form data before jQuery.serialize() or an inverse to jQuery.serialize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and I want to gather the data from a form and then manipulate it BEFORE I serialize it. The form object itself is a very complex beast that contains all of its descendant DOM nodes, etc, etc.

Basically, what I want is the serialized data but in an unserialized format.

I can do something like this:

```
function unser(serdata) {
    var data = {};
    var str = unescape(serdata);
    var pairs = str.split('&');
    for (var i=0;i<pairs.length;i++) {
        var pp = pairs[i].split('=');
        data[pp[0]] = pp[1];
    }
    return data;
}
```

And then when I do this:

```
unser( $('form').serialize() );
```

I have an object of the data, which I can then manipulate and then serialize it and send it to the backend server. But surely, **there must be a jQuery way of doing this that I am not seeing?**

It would almost make sense to have something like:

```
$('form').formData();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get form data before jQuery.serialize()

You want [`$('form').serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). You can then modify the result, and when you're done, pass it to `$.param`

```
$.param($('form').serializeArray())
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$('form').serialize()
```

Comment: Looking for a way to do the exact opposite of this as stated in the question. You have simply reiterated what I already stated in the question. How can I make the question clearer?

Comment: Hmmm how about using the simple method of vanilla JavaScript. http://jsfiddle.net/c8j6x/ is a nice code like jQuery serialize but as you can see you can modify it to be able to manipulate fields and values

Comment: @Octopus: What I've done is find you a jquery function, `X.serializeArray()`, that is roughly equivalent to your `unser( X.serialize() )`. My `X.serializeArray()` is your `X.formData()`. Is that not exactly what you asked for?

Comment: Okay then. I feel this is a really poorly named function as it isn't really serializing the data, but it is organized in a fairly reasonable manner, not that that's your fault. However, if you'd posted its actual output I may have been convinced sooner.

Comment: @Octopus: Think of it as halfway through the serialization process, and the name makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

> [@Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29153043/3210837) above is correct.
>   However, if you've got the serialised data (such as from a form post or from  a query string), this plugin will allow you to decode and use the data.

I found [`jQuery.deserialize`](https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize), a jQuery plugin that is the inverse to `jQuery.serialize()` which you could use like this:

```
$('form').deserialize( $('form').serialize() );
```

It supports deserialising complex types, such as arrays (i.e. multiple selects and checkbox arrays - see the documentation on [`jQuery.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for examples of these) and objects (see http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject).

Since a query string is the same as form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), you can also use this plugin to properly decode query strings.

Comment: This probably works, but if I have to use a plugin I may as well just use my code snippet.

Comment: @Octopus Yes, that's correct - but if you've got more complex types, like checkbox arrays, your solution won't work.